# tkinter image viewer buttons not going to correct image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm trying to create an image viewer with **Tkinter** but the problem is whenever I click the forward button *(to go to the next image)*, the back button *(which goes to the previous image)* is still disabled. For some reason though when I go to the third image it is enabled, another problem is when I reach the first image again the back button doesn't disable *( although it does at the start when the program runs )*.

I haven't added the images yet if your curious.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title('Image Viewer')

img = PhotoImage(file='yes.gif')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)
  
# images

stars_gif = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('yes.gif'))
stars_label = Label(image = stars_gif)

stars_label.grid(
  row = 0,
  column = 0,
  columnspan = 8,
  pady = 13,
  padx = 13
)

current_image = 1

cyan_shiftlock = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('cyanshiftlock.png'))
cyan_shiftlock_label = Label(image = cyan_shiftlock)

icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('icon.ico'))
icon_label = Label(image = icon)

exit_button = Button(root, text = "Exit", command = root.quit)

# main logic and stuff

images_list = [stars_gif, cyan_shiftlock, icon]
images_label = [stars_label, cyan_shiftlock_label, icon_label]

for image in images_list:
  print(image)

for image_label in images_label:
  print(image_label)

exit_button.grid(
  row = 1,
  column = 4
)

disabled_button = True

def back_command():
  global current_image
  global disabled_button
  global back_button
  
  if current_image <= 1:
    back_button["state"] = DISABLED
    disabled_button = True

  if current_image != 1:
    back_button["state"] = NORMAL
    disabled_button = False

  if current_image >= 3:
    forward_button["state"] = DISABLED

  if current_image != 3:
    forward_button["state"] = NORMAL


  current_image -= 2
  print(current_image)

def forward_command():
  global current_image
  global forward_button
  
  if current_image >= 3:
    forward_button["state"] = DISABLED

  if current_image != 3:
    forward_button["state"] = NORMAL

  if current_image <= 1:
    back_button["state"] = DISABLED
    disabled_button = True

  if current_image != 1:
    back_button["state"] = NORMAL
    disabled_button = False
    
  current_image += 2
  print(current_image)

back_button = Button(root, text = "<<", state = NORMAL, command = lambda : back_command())

back_button.grid(
  row = 1,
  column = 0
)

if current_image <= 1:
  back_button["state"] = DISABLED

forward_button = Button(root, text = ">>", state = NORMAL, command = lambda : forward_command())

forward_button.grid(
  row = 1,
  column = 7
)

root = mainloop()
```

Comment: You are setting the button states based on the current image number, *not* the new image number that will result from the button being pressed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that-